# Как отследить пользователя от чат-бота до целевого действия в ПП?

Tags: php

Пользователь заходит в бота в телеграмм, бот записывает его в бд по id в телеге(он для всех уникальный) Далее человек переходит по ссылке: мойсайт.ру/=idпользователя. На моем сайте есть ссылка на (к примеру) оформление карты банка, он нажимает по ссылке далее попадает на сайт банка, заказывает карту. Партнерская программа сообщает мне о заказе. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы я понимал, что именно этот пользователь с определенным Id в телеге, что именно он сделал целевое действие. Типо отследить.

Может есть хотя бы какие-то мысли по этому поводу?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ответ - частично.

Вы можете отследить пользователя и его действия у себя на сайте. Понять какой именно из пользователей стал клиентом банка вы можете только при совместной работе с самим банком.

### Отслеживание у себя на сайте

Поставьте себе аналитику от яндекса или гугла, добавьте нужную цель (клик по ссылке), для этого есть различные JS цели, которые позволят вам передать в аналитику достижение цели (уход на сайт банка) и направить пользователя на сайт.

Самих пользователей можно отслеживать разными способами. Например вы можете брать id пользователя при заходе на сайт, записывать его в сессию и передавать в цель в момент клика значение из сессии как данные.

Можете заменить ссылку с ID на UTM метку. Мол рекламная кампания - "телеграмм", пользователь - "такой-то id".
Это будет удобно использовать для отслеживания действия пользователей на сайте. Смотреть чем занимаются ваши клиенты из телеграмма на ресурсе.

### Отслеживание совместно с банком

Вам нужно обратиться в банк с просьбой информировать вас о том, какой именно клиент оформил заявку на карту, а какой нет. Для этого потребуется передавать по ссылке через GET ID пользователя.

Далеко не факт что такое решение напишут специально для вас, но предполагаю что в банке скорее всего уже есть подобное отслеживание.

По крайней мере мне кажется разумным, чтобы оно было.